# How to scrape a url having no of pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a webpage which is having a no of page in it how can I scrape those pages to get the Information which I want. Suppose I am Scraping a URL http://i.cantonfair.org.cn/en/ExpProduct.aspx?corpid=0776011226&categoryno=446
and this page is having two page how can I scrape those total pages and get the total product list.

What I did till now:
I am scraping a url from their I am scraping a particular url through regex
and trying to go to that url and from that link their are no of other pages contain information link product name. And I want to get that product name from all the pages.

My Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
import json
response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://i.cantonfair.org.cn/en/ExpProduct.aspx?corpid=0776011226&categoryno=446")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
productlink = soup.find_all("a", href=re.compile(r"ExpProduct\.aspx\?corpid=[0-9]+.categoryno=[0-9]+"))
productlink = ([link["href"] for link in productlink])
print (productlink)
```

After this I am stuck. I am using python 3.5.1 and Beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scrape the page for pictures, I'd advise [CSS Selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

Get the list of items, afterwards You can search for the next page. when you stop getting the next page you know you're done.

```
def get_next_page(soup):
    pages = soup.select('div[id="AspNetPager1] a[href]')
    for page in pages:
        if page.text == 'Next':
            return page

response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://i.cantonfair.org.cn/en/ExpProduct.aspx?corpid=0776011226&categoryno=446")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
url = 'http://i.cantonfair.org.cn/en/'
products = []

next_page = get_next_page(soup)
while next_page is not None:
    products += soup.select('div[class="photolist"] li')
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url + next_page['href'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
    next_page = get_next_page(soup)
products += soup.select('div[class="photolist"] li')

product_names = set()
for product in products:
    product_names.add(product.text)

print(product_names)
```

Comment: I just want to get the product name how to get that ?

Comment: and it doesn't seems it is to next page.

Comment: If you will test it in an interpreter you can see that there is indeed a request to the next page. Also, you can see that the size increases in the length of Items found.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I understand, what you would like to do is crawl a couple pages and scrape them as well.

I would suggest you to give a look at [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/).

You can crawl webpages and scrape them, the [Documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/) contains a tutorial and is pretty good in my opinion.